# PHP DOMDocument->getElementByID adding Â in place of empty <span>

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm using PHP's DOMDocument object to parse some HTML (fetched with cURL). When I get an element by ID and output it, any empty `<span> </span>` tags get an additional character and become `<span>Â </span>`.

The Code:

```
<?php
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->validateOnParse = true;

    $document->loadHTML( curl_exec($handle) );
    curl_close($handle);

    $element = $document->getElementById( __ELEMENT_ID__ );

    echo $document->saveHTML(); 
    echo $document->saveHTML($element);
?>
```

The `$document->saveHTML()` command behaves as expected and prints out the entire page. BUT, like I say above, on the `echo $document->saveHTML($element)` command transforms empty `<span>` tags into `<span>Â </span>`.

This happens to all `<span> </span>` tags within `$element`.

*What in this process (of getting the element by ID and outputting the element) is inserting this extra character?* I'm could work around it, but I'm more interested in getting to the root.

Comment: It's a non-breaking space in source and output: `<span>&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: Make sure that the source doesn't contain invisible characters.

Comment: I've confirmed that it contains no invisible characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by setting the character encoding of the page. The page I was fetching did not have a defined character encoding, and my page was just a snippet without defined header info. When I added

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

The problem disappeared.