# PHP's domdocument inserts Â symbol

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

Given some HTML, I apply the http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php class to it, save it, and the `Â` symbol is occasionally inserted.  It appears to happen with tags which have a single white-space (opposed to a `&nbsp;`), but doesn't appear to be absolute (only the first `<span>` element exhibits this phenomena).  I've tried adding encoding when displaying the resulting HTML as recommended by [PHP DOMDocument->getElementByID adding Â in place of empty <span>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629351/php-domdocument-getelementbyid-adding-%C3%82-in-place-of-empty-span), however, the problem persists.  What causes this and how is it prevented?

In case you are interested why I am doing so.  I have an application where I am substituting HTML images with text.  When copying and pasting HTML from an Outlook email to a TinyMCE editor, and then parsing the HTML, I experience this behavior.

```
<?php
$message = <<<EOT
<p>Start</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Phone: (444) 777-7777</span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
</p>
<p>End</p>
EOT;
    echo('<p>Initial HTML:</p> '.$message);
    $message_encoded = utf8_encode($message);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($message);
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $message=$doc->saveHTML($body);
    echo('<p>Final HTML:</p> '.$message);
    echo('<p>Initial HTML encoded:</p> '.$message_encoded);
    $doc->loadHTML($message_encoded);
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $message_encoded=$doc->saveHTML($body);
    echo('<p>Final HTML:</p> '.$message_encoded);
?>
```

Output:

```
<p>Initial HTML:</p> <p>Start</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Phone: (444) 777-7777</span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
</p>
<p>End</p><p>Final HTML:</p> <body>
<p>Start</p>
<p>Â </p>
<p>Â </p>
<p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Â <br></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Phone: (444)Â 777-7777</span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br></span>
</p>
<p>End</p>
</body><p>Initial HTML encoded:</p> <p>Start</p>
<p>Â </p>
<p>Â </p>
<p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Â <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Phone: (444)Â 777-7777</span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br /></span>
</p>
<p>End</p><p>Final HTML:</p> <body>
<p>Start</p>
<p>ÃÂ </p>
<p>ÃÂ </p>
<p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">ÃÂ <br></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br></span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;">Phone: (444)ÃÂ 777-7777</span>
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-serif';color:#000080;"> <br></span>
</p>
<p>End</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>' . $message);
```

By prepending the string to your HTML string, you will tell the PHP to use UTF-8 as encoding.

Credit: https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/9401853

Answer (score 1):

PHP DOM extension operates in `utf8`. Similar byte-encoding issues apply to XML documents. Is your current encoding `ISO-8859-1` by any chance?

As advised on http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php :

> The DOM extension uses UTF-8 encoding. Use utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() to work with texts in ISO-8859-1 encoding or Iconv for other encodings.

Try to modify that part as follows:

```
<p>End</p>
EOT;
    $message = utf8_encode($message); // this should fix it.
    echo('<p>Initial HTML:</p> '.$message);
```

Also set script output as `UTF8` and save documents in `UTF8` to resolve many future encoding-related problems.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks DeDee. Did so, and now I get two Ã instead of one! See revised original post.  Looking at phpinfo, it appears that my system configuration is not utf8. Specifically, I have exif and iconv set to ISO-8859-15. Maybe the issue?

Comment: Very likely your `ISO` causes the problem. Characters saved in a text document in `ISO-8859-*` are so sent to PHP interpreter. Backup all of your documents then try to convert all of them to `UTF8`, some characters may get broken, so check documents after conversion. Once PHP documents, all input and the environment are in `UTF8` you should not experience a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `$message_encoded = mb_convert_encoding($message_encoded , 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` after `$message_encoded = $doc->saveHTML($body);`

Comment: This made things much worse for me. Before I was getting only an occasional â added, but after things like "I'm" became I&acirc;&#128;&#153;m

Answer (score 0):

As DeDee said, your issue is caused by `iso-8859-1` characters being converted into `utf-8`. Note that white-space is *also* considered a character.

There are three solutions:

1. Make sure the input is in UTF-8,
2. Set your server's charset to iso-8859-1
3. Properly convert all characters into UTF-8.

I personally recommend 1, and don't recommend 2.

### To Accomplish 1)

Make sure you use a text editor, such as Notepad++, to create your files. *Don't* use text editors such as Microsoft Word. Rule-of-thumb here is to just make sure any editor you use to create software uses UTF-8 encoding.

### To Accomplish 2)

In a top-level `.htaccess` file:

```
AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
```

In the `<head>` of your HTML files:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

### To Accomplish 3)

Here's a snippet of code that you can use:

```
//Convert character encoding to UTF-8
function replace_non_utf_characters($string) {
    /**
     * This array consists of $key=>$value pairs, where $key
     * is the character needing to be replaced, and $value is
     * the character $key is replaced by. Add characters to
     * this array as needed.
     */
    $replacement_array = array(
            chr(145) => "'", //the chr(#) are all Microsoft-encoded equivalents (e.g. open/close "smart" quotes)
            chr(146) => "'",
            chr(147) => "\"",
            chr(148) => "\"",
            chr(149) => "&#8226;",
            chr(150) => "&ndash;",
            chr(151) => "&mdash;",
            chr(153) => "&#8482;",
            chr(169) => "&copy;",
            chr(174) => "&reg;"
        );
    foreach($replacement_array as $key=>$replacement) {
        $string = str_replace($key, $replacement, $string);
    }
    //Force UTF-8 encoding, so that there will always be an output
    return mb_convert_encoding(str_replace(chr(194), '', mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", 'HTML-ENTITIES')), 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I agree with Option 2 not being the best choice.  My difficulty is that the user, not me inputs content into my form editor, and I have no control whether they take content from Microsoft Word.  I will look into Option 3.  Also, maybe there is some way to make TinyMCE do this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> In case you are interested why I am doing so. I have an application
>   where I am substituting HTML images with text. When copying and
>   pasting HTML from an Outlook email to a TinyMCE editor, and then
>   parsing the HTML, I experience this behavior.

Microsoft Word and Outlook will add a bunch of garbage when cut-and-pasted into TinyMCE.  Just add the TinyMCE plugin "paste".  Still need to deal with any

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$htm = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",$htm);
$doc->loadHTML($htm) ;
```

It was the only way I could get rid of the Â symbol.